# Efficiently summing log quantities

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, sum, probability

Working in C++, I'd like to find the sum of some quantities, and then take the log of the sum:

```
log(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n)
```

However, I do not have the quantities themselves, I only have their log'd values:

```
l_1 = log(a_1), l_2 = log(a_2), ... , l_n = log(a_n)
```

Is there any efficient way to get the log the sum of the a_i's? I'd like to avoid

```
log(s) = log(exp(l_1) + exp(l_2) + ... + exp(l_n))
```

if possible - exp becomes a bottleneck as the calculation is done many times.

Comment: Hey, that's a [math question](http://jblevins.org/notes/log-sum-exp) in disguise!

Comment: Too bad you're not looking for log(a_1 * ... * a_n)--you could just sum the log values you have!

Comment: What are those quantities? Are there any relation among them?

Comment: The a_i's are the probability masses at a random sample of points from a complex model - no simple relationships between them.

Comment: @Mike Ohh well. Sometimes life shows its ugly face. Nothing to my knowledge. You may try to ask [`here`](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think you have no choice but to find `2**c_i` for each `c=log(a_i)` to find `a_i`. This means dealing with large numbers, and it means a relatively slow operation. Maybe the guys at math.stackexchange.com have a better insight for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How large is n?

This quantity is known as log-sum-exp and Lieven Vandenberghe talks about it on page 72 of his [book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/). He also has an [optimization package](http://cvxmod.net/builtinatoms.html) which uses this operation, and from a brief look, it seems as if he doesn't do anything special there, just exponentiates and adds. Perhaps exponentiation is not a serious bottleneck when n is small enough for the vector to fit into memory.

This operation often comes up in modeling and the bottleneck there is the sheer number of terms. Magnitude of n=2^100 is common, where the terms are implicitly represented. In such cases, there are various tricks to approximating this quantity relying on convexity of log-sum-exp. The simplest trick --  approximate log(s) as max(l1,l2,....,ln)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any way, because, in general, there is no way to calculate

> e<sup>x</sup> + e<sup>y</sup>

using addition and only **one** exponentiation, which is equivalent to what you're asking.

---

As was mentioned in Frédéric Hamidi's comment above, even if you do sum the exponents, you have another problem to worry about:  overflow.  The [link he gave](http://jblevins.org/notes/log-sum-exp) gives a pretty good solution *(following Fortran code copied from that link)*:

```
function log_sum_exp(v) result(e)
  real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: v   ! Input vector
  real                           :: e   ! Result is log(sum(exp(v)))
  real                           :: c   ! Shift constant

  ! Choose c to be the element of v that is largest in absolute value.
  if ( maxval(abs(v)) > maxval(v) ) then
     c = minval(v)
  else
     c = maxval(v)
  end if

  e = log(sum(exp(v-c))) + c
end function log_sum_exp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following identity:

```
log( a + b ) = log(a) + log( 1 + (b/a) )
```

Comment: That is what Frédéric Hamidi's link uses for preventing overflow; but, how does this help with more than two variables?

Comment: @BlueRaja, it doesn't help, if I'm not mistaken you still have to compute exponents for each term. To put it romantically, questioner wants to predict the future by crossing log()ed curves, so he has to pay the price and compute all the exponents (and be wary of overflow/underflow).

Comment: Instead of needing n calls to exp(), you now need n/2 calls to exp() and n/2 calls to log().  Log() should be fast due to native cpu instructions.  exp() ~ no so much...

Answer (score 1):

It's not very elegant, but you could try the following.

- Obtain `lg a_i` from `log a_i` (divide by `log 2`).
- Let `lg a_i` = `k` + `q` where `k` is integer and `q` is real and `0 >= q >= 1`
- Get `a_i` with 2<sup>k</sup>`pow(2,q)` (use bit shifting for 2<sup>k</sup> = `1 << k`).
- You can speed up `pow(2,q)` with precomputed tables of limited precision for [0,1]

So the whole idea is to leverage a fast power-of-2 function. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If s_k := `sum(a_1 + ... + a_k)` then
s_{k+1} == `s_k + f(l_{k+1} - s_k)`, where

```
f(x) := log(1+exp(x))
```

This function `f` can probably be computed with a Taylor series or similar with a speed comparable to `exp`, and possibly even inlined.

That only saves about two mathematical functions, but it might be a useful starting point.